# Iterating through JSON using an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm creating a template picker/roulette Slack bot. The goal is to message the bot and pass in arguments like the command line, and have it iterate through a JSON object and randomly select a template that matches the criteria. The user should be able to pass in any amount of arguments too.

*Example*: I message the bot with this `Roulette -s -i` the arguments are `-s` which stands for sidebar and `-i` which stands for index. So the bot needs to find a template that has both a sidebar and an index.

This is a sample of my JSON object:

```
{
  name: "foo",
  index: {
    hasIndex: true
  },
  sidebar: {
    hasSidebar: true
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
controller.hears(["roulette", "^pattern$"],["direct_message", "direct_mention", "mention"], function(bot,message) {
  const data = require('./data.js');
  const nodeList = []
  const args = message.text.match(/-\w/g);
  const obj = {
    '-s': '.sidebar.hasSidebar',
    '-i': '.index.hasIndex'
  }

  args.forEach(function(arg) {
    var path = obj[arg];
    // console.log(path) when passing arguments -s or -i
    // the path variable correctly gives me .sidebar.hasSidebar, etc    

    data.forEach(function(node) {
      // console.log(node) Gives me my data set
      // console.log(node.path) This is the issue, it returns undefined.
      if (node.path === true) {
        nodeList.push(node.name)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My question is why can I not use `node.path` if `node` is correctly giving me the data set? Shouldn't I be able to add `path` and complete the path so the forEach loops through? Instead I am getting `undefined` and I don't understand why.

**EDIT**

I've updated my code:

```
  var nodeList = data.filter(function(node) {
    return args.every(function(arg) {
      return obj[arg](node);
    });
  });

  const obj = {
    '-s': function (node) { return node.sidebar.hasSidebar; },
    '-i': function (node) { return node.index.hasIndex; },
  };


  data.forEach(function(node) {
    args.forEach(function(arg) {
      var pathTester = obj[arg];

      if (pathTester(node)) {
        nodeList.push(node.name)
      }
    });
  });
```

1) Did I swap the loops correctly?

2) I don't quite understand how nodeList is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
if (node.path === true)
```

...you are looking for the property with name `path`. This has nothing to do with the variable `path` which you declared earlier on.

Looking up a dynamic property-chain based on a dot-separated string (like `'.sidebar.hasSidebar'`) is not possible with this syntax. You would have to call `eval()` to achieve that, like this:

```
if (eval('node' + path) === true)
```

This works, but because `eval` has a bad reputation, I would suggest to define your `obj` with values that are functions instead of strings, like this:

```
const obj = {
    '-s': function (node) { return node.sidebar.hasSidebar; },
    '-i': function (node) { return node.index.hasIndex; },
};
```

... and then retrieve and call the function:

```
args.forEach(function(arg) {
    var pathTester = obj[arg];

    data.forEach(function(node) {
        if (pathTester(node)) {
            nodeList.push(node.name);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Correction to Algorithm

Now, the above answers the question, but as you mentioned the following:

> *Example:* I message the bot with this `Roulette -s -i` the arguments are `-s` which stands for sidebar and `-i` which stands for index. So the bot needs to find a template that has both a sidebar and an index.

... I need to point out that your current code will push nodes to the node list even if only one condition is true, and the same nodes may be pushed to it several times.

If you want nodes to only be added when all conditions are true, then swap your loops and make sure you only add nodes when the (then) inner loop returns true for all args.

At the same time I'll suggest the use of `every` and `filter` functions:

```
var nodeList = data.filter(function(node) {
    return args.every(function(arg) {
        return obj[arg](node);
    });
});
```

Note that this *replaces* the `forEach` loops you have. The complete code would look like this:

```
controller.hears(["roulette", "^pattern$"],["direct_message", "direct_mention", "mention"], function(bot,message) {
    const data = require('./data.js');
    const args = message.text.match(/-\w/g);
    const obj = {
        '-s': function (node) { return node.sidebar.hasSidebar; },
        '-i': function (node) { return node.index.hasIndex; },
    };
    var nodeList = data.filter(function(node) {
        return args.every(function(arg) {
            return obj[arg](node);
        });
    });
});
```

#### More about `filter` and `every`

The above is taking the power of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Without these methods, the code could look like this:

```
var nodeList = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
    // Check if this node should be added
    var addNode = true; // start positive...
    args.forEach(function(arg) {
        var pathTester = obj[arg];
        if (pathTester(node) !== true) {
            // if not all paths are true, don't add the node 
            addNode = false;
        }
    });
    if (addNode) {
        nodeList.push(node);
    }
});
```

#### More about comparing with `true`

When writing code like this:

```
if (property === true)
```

... *and* you know for sure that *property* is always a boolean (if it is defined), then you can just write this:

```
if (property)
```

This is because an `if` statement needs something that evaluates to a boolean. But if *property* already is a boolean, there is no need to make a comparison with `true`. There are three possibilities for *property*. Either it is:

- `undefined`
- `false`
- `true`

When one of these three values is the `if` expression, only the last one `true` will make the `if` condition `true`. `undefined` is considered a falsy value.

However, if *property* could also be a non-boolean value, like a number, string or object, and you only want to respond to the exact value of `true` (not any other value), then you **do** need to test like `=== true`. Without it, also non-zero numerical values, non-empty strings and objects would pass the test.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! That makes sense about node.path and how that's searching the property of 'path' and of course that doesn't exist in my data. I've updated my code and trying to wrap my head around 2 things:

1) How does it know to retrieve templates that are 'true' with their flag?

2) How come when I pass in 2 arguments -s and -i it doesn't give me back templates that contain BOTH? It seems to give me all templates that contain an index and all templates that contain a sidebar, but not all templates that contain BOTH an index and sidebar?

Comment: (1) If your property is a boolean value (false or true, or undefined when it is missing) then it is not necessary to write `if (property === true)`. You can just write `if (property)`. This is because an `if` needs a boolean. If the property is already a boolean, then that is enough. But add it if you think you need it: `if (pathTester(node) === true)`. (2) I added a section about that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for being clear and updating the answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: Any additional help please @trincot ? I don't fully grasp the concept.

Comment: The `filter` and `every` code replaces the `forEach` code block, and represent the two loops (both `filter` and `every` loop over the elements, just like `forEach`, but do more). I added this precision in my answer some explanation how it works by giving an equivalent piece of code (don't add that :) ).

Comment: I should add that you don't do anything with the  `bot` and `message` arguments to your `controller.hears` callback, but if you have more questions related to that, please ask a new question.